# plotlyProxyInvoke doesn`t update data properly?

Tags: plotly, updates

I am trying to update a plot using `plotlyProxyInvoke` and it seems to ignore one dimension
I use this code to render my graph, getting this
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAItx.png)

```
observeEvent(input$test_button_Out,{
output$plot_data_tot \<- renderPlotly({
 filtered_act() %...\>% {
 data \<- .
 data \<- data %\>% filter(Dataz == "Grupo 1" | Dataz == "Grupo 2")
 data \<- data %\>% select(Datay, Dataz) %\>% group_by(Datay, Dataz) %\>% dplyr::summarize(Numero = n())
 data \<- replace(data, is.na(data), "N/D")
 if (is.null(data) || typeof(data) == "character")
 return()
 plot_data \<- plot_ly(
   x = data$Numero,
   y = data$Datay,
   type = "bar",
   color = data$Dataz,
   )  %\>% layout(title = "---------------------", margin = mrg,
    barmode = 'group',
    yaxis = list(categoryorder = 'total ascending'),
    xaxis = list(side = "top"
    )) %\>%
  plotly::config(displayModeBar = FALSE)

    plot_data
  }
})

})
```

And try to update data using this other button

```
`observeEvent(input$test_button_Inv,{

  # Actualizar datos
  filtered_act() %...>% {
    data <- .
    data <- data %>% filter(Dataz == "Grupo 1"| Dataz == "Grupo 2")
    data <- data %>% select(Datay, Dataz) %>% group_by(Datay, Dataz) %>% dplyr::summarize(Numero = n())
    data <- replace(data, is.na(data), "N/D")
    if (is.null(data) || typeof(data) == "character")
      return()
    view(data)
    proxy <- plotlyProxy("plot_data_tot", session = session)
    proxy %>% plotlyProxyInvoke("update", list(x = list(data$Numero), y = list(data$Datay),color = list(data$Dataz)))
  }

})\`
```

with this result
[updated result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIsSv.png)

Somebody solved this problem. Is there something wrong?

```
If I eliminate ,color = list(data$Dataz) the result is the same
If change color = list(data$Dataz) by color = data$Dataz
```

the result is the same...

it  seems to ignore the dimension color